# Pasting values only to another column automatically based on time passed

Tags: google-apps-script

I am currently working on setting up a Google Doc to track live web data using ImportXML and want to copy those figures to other columns after specific time intervals. I am tracking the date info is entered and then for every 15 days automatically copying this info to another column for multiple accounts. Here is my code so far which is working on row 1, but now that I have it working for one cell I want to do this for the whole column individually:

```
function moveValuesOnly() {
var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet()
var currentValue = sheet.getRange("B4").getValue();
if (currentValue == (15)) {


var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
var source = ss.getRange("H4");
var copyRange = ss.getRange("H4");
var l = ss.getDataRange().getValues().length;
var pasteRange = ss.getRange("R4");
pasteRange.setValues(copyRange.getValues());
}}

var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet()
var currentValue = sheet.getRange("B5").getValue();
if (currentValue == (30)) {


var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
var source = ss.getRange("H4");
var copyRange = ss.getRange("H4");
var l = ss.getDataRange().getValues().length;
var pasteRange = ss.getRange("T5");
pasteRange.setValues(copyRange.getValues());
}
```

Is there any way to have it evaluate line by line and not all at once? I am guessing I should not be using range, but I have no idea how else to do this. Any help will be very much appreciated!! If I can clarify anything let me know.

THANK YOU!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

How are you invoking this script ? As a formula in the spreadsheet or from the script editor ? 
If you're using it as a formula, you can read the range directly. 
If you're invoking it from the script editor, you can make small changes to your script to make it work across a range larger than a cell. See the code below

```
function moveValuesOnly() {
var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
var range= sheet.getRange("B4:R20");
var currentValue = range.getValues(); // Change 20 to whatever you want
var COL_B = 0;  // relative to col B 
var COL_H = 6;
var COL_R = 16; 

for(var i = 0 ; i < currentValue.length ; i++){
if (currentValue[i][0] == (15)) {

// Copy value in H4, H5 etc to R4, R5 etc. 
currentValue[i][COL_R] = currentValue[i][COL_H];
}
range.setValues(currentValue);
}
```

I haven't tested it but if you find any minor errors feel free to fix it:)

Comment: Thanks so much @Srik! That was a huge help in getting the data to move appropriately, but it did cause one issue in the way I am setting up my doc which I mention here if you have any insight:http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19232963/losing-importxml-functions-when-running-my-current-script

Seriously thank you for taking the time to answer me, I really appreciate!